# Google chrome CSS attributes acting strangely

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm currently using twitter bootstraps in my HTML pages, and I want a header with a certain width :

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="padding-left:2px">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/myimage.png")" alt="image" style="width:10%"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Firefox, it's displayed correctly (the header is 10% of the page), but on chrome, it's displayed as if width was not set.

The strange thing here, is that when I inspect the element, there is :

```
element.style {
width: 10%;
}
```

Width is checked, but when I uncheck it, and recheck it, the image is displayed correctly...

Nutshell : Google chrome does not take into account my style, but does when I inspect, uncheck then check the css attribute...

Comment: Yes, this is strange. It would be great to have a jsFiddle to see it. Did you try just restarting chrome ? Is chrome up to date ?

Comment: Ok so, I did try on JsFiddle, and as it worked, I decided to take a look at both consoles of browsers.
It seems like CSP (content security policy) is not handled similarly by Chrome and Firefox, and basically, chrome was locking way much more content than firefox.
That's quite obscure for me, but I guess that I'll just need to change my CSP settings for chrome.

Comment: Is it now normal to write endtags for img like that `</img>` ? Just asking, seeing this for first time in case of images.

Comment: @Ms.Nobody nope, it should be `<img />`